# Duplication with INSERT mysqli

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

When I insert the username and the email in my DB the data are duplicated. So I have two id for the same user. When I echo the affected number of rows for the query the results is 1. Can someone help me with this?

```
 <form name="field" method="post" action="test.php">
     <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
     <input name="username" id="username" type="text"/><br>
     <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
     <input name="email" id="email" type="text"/><br>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" id="submit" />
    </form>


    <?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'project');

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

    $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `project`.`registration` (`id`,`username`,`email`) VALUES ('id','$username','$email')");

    $result = $mysqli->affected_rows;

    echo $result;

    ?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `id`, you have used in insert statement?

Comment: Affected Rows shows how many rows were changed/added so when you add one then it shows 1

Comment: are you double clicking on the submit button? I have seen this problem many years ago and that is exactly what was happening. If you put some additional checks in there to prevent duplicates being entered it might help.

Comment: You could query your DB first before insertion, using `mysqli_num_rows` then if there's no match, proceed with insertion. That's one method that I use.

Comment: Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use only prepared statements and a PDO wrapper due security reasons. Now to the Problem. What is your db scheme? Where did you get your `id` variable from? It's a constant in the way you use it. Note that if your scheme say id int auto_increment primary key. It increments by itself so you don't have to set the id by hand.

change

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `project`.`registration` (`id`,`username`,`email`) VALUES ('id','$username','$email')");
```

to

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `project`.`registration` (`username`,`email`) VALUES ('$username','$email')");
```

Comment: May I have a comment from upvoter? Explaining whatever use of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a unique column where possible. For example if the username is unique, you have to make it unique in the registration table also.

for example:

```
CREATE TABLE Registration ( 
username varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
email varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
id INT NOT NULL );
```

By adding this constraint to your table, you should be able to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: This answer is the only near to the problem so far. Yet it doesn't answer why duplicated query happens at all, which is the main question, I believe.